# Why are wizard dialogs called "wizards"?

Tags: history, terminology

I was talking with my non-techie wife tonight.  She was talking about how she was training staff to use some new software.  The software made heavy use of wizards to accomplish tasks.  Her question to me was "Why are wizards called 'wizards?'  Are they made by some nerd with an interest in Dungeons & Dragons?"

I realized that, while the "nerd" and "Dungeons & Dragons" were true in my case, I didn't know the origin of of the term "wizard" as it relates to a part of an application that guides a user through some difficult process.

I'm curious to see what thoughts others here have on this great and weighty question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My impression is that it's related to the meaning of wizard that's similar to "expert". A UI wizard is like a (*very* simple) [expert system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expert_system). The wizard/"expert" asks you a series of questions to figure out what you want, and then they use their "expertise" to generate a result.

Comment: Yes, and this is also implied at the Wikipedia article for the term: 
[Microsoft Manual of Style for Technical Publications urges technical writers to refer to these assistants as "wizards" (...). In countries where the concept of wizard does not convey the ***idea of helpfulness*** or is offensive, the manual suggests using the term "assistant" instead.](Emphasis mine). So it's like a "Wizard", i.e an expert in some field, that comes to your assistance.

Comment: Interesting, I've never really thought of a wizard as an expert system.  Makes sense though.

Comment: Found this through googling. Here's a far better answer. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65728/origin-of-the-term-wizard-in-computing

Answer (score 4):

One of the original Wizard interfaces, was with Microsoft Publisher 2.0.

The wizard part came after the last dialog page, where it would 'magically' perform the actions required to achieve the task requested in the wizard, and actually *show* you how to do it. For example, running the Greeting Card Wizard, would show you how to  set the aspect ratio, paper size, etc.

I guess user interface testing showed that not enough people were following the wizard tutorial, and just skipped through it to get the desired result, because this functionality was dropped in later versions of Publisher.

Answer (score 2):

Because they *magically* guide the user through the process to achieve the users goal.

Comment: I think this is close - I think it is more like the 'magic' is that after asking you a bunch of questions and reach the finish, it 'magically' does all the required changes in order to match the information you gave.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Microsoft invented and introduced the term, no doubt for marketing related reasons.

Comment: not sure if that was a bash or not, but you gotta give MS credit for coming up with some of the coolest names in the industry. Hell, "Windows" - as simple as it is of a name, it is actually pretty cool.

Comment: MS didn't invent the term Windows, it was a pre-existing popular term used to refer to both text- and graphical-based software which displayed things in 'windows', including graphical operating systems, see http://www.guidebookgallery.org/articles/microsoftdoeswindows for an interesting read.  See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_%28computing%29 for the history - apparently 'windows' started at Standford Research Institute, with further development by Xerox corp.

Comment: "bash"?! marketing is important, for good or for bad - and naming things is an area where marketeers and engineers (esp. software developers) both often operate, so it's particularly relevant that the two groups of professionals understand each other to come up with useful, effective names.

Comment: @thomasrutter: But they sure did market that term...  Interestingly enough, Microsoft does NOT hold a registered trademark for Windows.  The USPTO found the term is too generic and that it can not be trademarked..

Answer (score 0):

I guess because user interfaces that configured things that were previously done manually must have seemed like magic to users.  It's a pretty good analogy if you think about it - this little config app is doing many many things with a single "wave of the wand" as it were.